# Gazebo simulation time speed up

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I have been trying to simulate two Turtlebot II on Gazebo.

I wonder if it is possible to perform simulations with time increased several times (pun). I'm not really concerned in visually observe the movements, but I want to run several times  the same simulation and store different measurements / data for statistical analysis of the project I'm working on.

Is this kind of high-speed simulation possible in Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151691/gazebo-simulation-time-speed-up./) by [Carlos Hdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5773/carlos-hdz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given that gazebo always performs real-time dynamics simulation, there are limits to the speed that can be achieved on commodity hardware. There are some options though:

- Get a faster computer
- Reduce dynamics simulation fidelity
  (time step, solver iterations). Might
  make simulation unstable though
- Reduce scenario/robot complexity  (simple geometries, switch off/don't
  use sensors you don't need)

If you only require a relatively abstract robot model, using Stage or the recently introduced STDR simulator instead might be another option.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlos Hdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5773/carlos-hdz/) on 2014-04-10**:
mmm... I will try them... Thank you!